# Cython - Accessing c type members of an extension type from a second extension type

Tags: python, cython

I have an extension type that contains some c pointers as members. I would like to expose these members so I can access them from a different extension type. Is there a way to do so?

This is how it basically looks like:

typeA.pxd:

```
cdef class typeA(object):
  cdef double *myArray
```

typeB.pyx:

```
cimport typeA
import typeA

cdef class typeB(object):
  typeA.typeA myA
  cdef someFunction(self):
    b = myA.myArray[0]
```

How can I access myArray from typeB (preferably without a python overhead)?

Comment: Please read the signature policy in Stack Overflow FAQ

Comment: You've got a load of syntax errors there, like using `cdef` instead of `cdef class`. If you fix those, you're done.

Comment: larsmans - this is not a syntax issue. I'm asking if there is a way to access members of an extension type without the conversion to python objects, but from a different extension type.